# How to wrap a function with accurate __code__.co_argcount?

Tags: python, function, decorator

Here is my problem, i'm working with an API,
precisely with a high-order function that only accepts functions with N arguments. (I cannot monkey-patch this API).

```
#this is an example of a high order function i may encounter
#there are many more of such functions in the API that require N ammount of arguments
#this example fct required 3 arg, but a valid solution should adapt to any required args count

def high_order_function(f):
    """high order function expecting a function with 3 arguments!""" 

    print(f"\nprocessing function {f.__name__}")
    if f.__code__.co_argcount!=3:
        raise Exception(f"Error Expecting a function with 3 arguments, the passed function got {f.__code__.co_argcount}")
    print("Function is Ok")

    #...
    return None
```

And my problem is that I simply cannot use any wrapper because of this check.
what am I supposed to do ?

```
def my_wrapper(func):
    import functools
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapped1!")
        r = func(*args,**kwargs)
        print("wrapped2!")
        return r
    return inner

def original(a, b, c):
    return None

wrapped = my_wrapper(original)

high_order_function(original)
#ok!

high_order_function(wrapped) 
#will cause error
#because wrapped.__code__.co_argcount == 0 and is readonly!
```

Comment: I think you could also look at the problem in the other direction, instead of wrapping the _original_ function just wrap the _high_order_function_, it should be much easier... or even just use a nested function with a call of _high_order_function_ in its body. It depends a bit on your strategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering, I found a pretty procedural way that might work for you.

The trick was to use `__code__.replace()`. There are some caveats, probably more than I know.

```py
def high_order_function(f):
    """high order function expecting a function with 3 arguments!"""

    print(f"\nprocessing function {f.__name__}")
    if f.__code__.co_argcount!=3:
        raise Exception(f"Error Expecting a function with 3 arguments, the passed function got {f.__code__.co_argcount}")
    print("Function is Ok")

    #...
    return None

def my_wrapper(func):
    import functools

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z):
        kwargs = locals().copy()
        del kwargs["func"]
        print("wrapped1!")
        r = func(**kwargs)  # func(*kwargs.values()) would work too
        print("wrapped2!")
        return r

    func_args = func.__code__.co_varnames
    inner.__code__ = inner.__code__.replace(co_varnames=func_args, co_argcount=len(func_args))

    return inner

def original(a, b, c):
    return None

wrapped = my_wrapper(original)

high_order_function(original)
high_order_function(wrapped)
```

Result

```
processing function original
Function is Ok

processing function original
Function is Ok
```

*`functools.wraps` changes the name of `inner` to `original`*

### Caveats

- `__code__.replace()` raised `ValueError: code: varnames is too small` when `inner`'s parameters were `*args` or `**kwargs`
- If `inner` instead had no parameters then `locals()` inside it would not get the supplied values, therefore you got the whole alphabet instead
- Inside `inner` you can access the parameters by the letter like normal if you're sure it´s supplied otherwise you'll get `IndexError: tuple index out of range`
- I recommend to use e.g. `kwargs.get("d")` instead
- `__code__.replace` may only be for 3.8+, it has `sys.version_info >= (3, 8)` in the source code

Answer (score 1):

Why not define 2 version of the `inner` function in your wrapper based on whether you need to pass the wrapped function to `higher_order_function` or not.

Something like this:

```
def high_order_function(f):
    """high order function expecting a function with 3 arguments!"""

    print(f"\nprocessing function {f.__name__}")
    if f.__code__.co_argcount != 3:
        raise Exception(
            f"Error Expecting a function with 3 arguments, the passed function got {f.__code__.co_argcount}")
    print("Function is Ok")

    # ...
    return None


def my_wrapper(func, higher_order_compatible=True):  # switch to control whether should be compatible with the higher_order_function or not
    import functools

    if higher_order_compatible:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):  # extra args to satisfy the condition
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r
    else:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):  # normal wrapper
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r

    return inner


def original(a, b, c):
    return None


wrapped_compat = my_wrapper(original, higher_order_compatible=True)
wrapped_nocompat = my_wrapper(original, higher_order_compatible=False)

print("Original")
high_order_function(original)
print("Compatible")
high_order_function(wrapped_compat)
print("Not compatible")
try:
    high_order_function(wrapped_nocompat)
except:
    print("no not working")
```

Results in:

```
Original
processing function original
Function is Ok

Compatible
processing function original
Function is Ok

Not compatible
processing function original
no not working
```

Comment: thanks for your input! it could work in this case, but it is not scalable ( let say there's another 100 high order function in the API with various argument count requisite that we cannot predict in advance )

is there a way to procedurally generate a function in the wrapper that has the same number of arguments?

Comment: Can't think of a simple solution outside of templating such a inner function with exec, maybe.

Comment: what if instead of a wrap we do a `inner = copy.deepcopy(func) ; inner.__call__ = new_call` ? see what i mean

Answer (score 1):

`co_argcount`: number of arguments (not including keyword only arguments, * or ** args)

Hence the goal is to bypass such definition. Make a fake signature with 3 fake parameters, these are taken into consideration by the code attribute `co_argcount`. Then the parameters of the original function **must** by passed as keys.

```
def wrapper(f):
    def extended_signature(fake1=None, fake2=None, fake3=None, **kwargs):
        return f(**kwargs)
    return extended_signature


def a(q, w): print(q, w)

a_wrapped = wrapper(a)

high_order_function(a_wrapped)(q=1, w=2)
#processing function true_signature
#Function is Ok
```

Answer (score 0):

well, here's a solution, couldn't find a procedural way to generate the functions... it scales up to 5 forced arguments

```
def my_wrapper(func):
    """see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73601340/how-to-wrap-a-function-with-accurate-code-argcount?noredirect=1#comment129973896_73601340
    yes this is a shit show, did not found a procedural way to generate functions. tried exec() code generation & was also a mess"""

    #find back the expected arguments so func.__code__.co_argcount will be accurate
    if (func.__defaults__ is not None):
          force_arg = func.__code__.co_argcount - len(func.__defaults__)
    else: force_arg = func.__code__.co_argcount

    import functools

    if (force_arg==0):
            
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(**kwargs):
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(**kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r

    elif (force_arg==1):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(a,**kwargs):
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(a,**kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r

    elif (force_arg==2):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(a,b,**kwargs):
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(a,b,**kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r

    elif (force_arg==3):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(a,b,c,**kwargs):
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(a,b,c,**kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r

    elif (force_arg==4):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(a,b,c,d,**kwargs):
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(a,b,c,d,**kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r

    elif (force_arg==5):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(a,b,c,d,e,**kwargs):
            print("wrapped1!")
            r = func(a,b,c,d,e,**kwargs)
            print("wrapped2!")
            return r

    else: raise Exception("my_wrapper() do not support more than 5 forced argument")

    return inner
```

Answer (score -1):

### This is an attempt to solve the problem

i feel like it's almost a potential solution

However it is not working as expected, strange. `f()`for a function object class is not as `f.__call__()` hmm

```
def my_wrapper(func):
    import copy

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapped front")
        r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("wrapped end")
        return r

    newfunc = copy.deepcopy(func)
    newfunc.__name__ = func.__name__ + "_wrapped"
    newfunc.__call__ = inner

    return newfunc

def original(a, b, c=6):
    print("original",a,b,c)
    return None

###testing if the original function work
high_order_function(original)
#will pass requirement

###testing if the wrap works?
high_order_function(my_wrapper(original))
#will pass requirement, however the wrap did not work
```

Comment: related on why it's not working. 
what a bummer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73601861/why-fct-call-is-not-the-same-as-fct