# why fct.__call__() is not the same as fct()?

Tags: python, function, class, callable

the `__call__` dunder method of a class is supposed to represent the operator `()`, correct?
if so, why the following code is not working as expected?

```
def f():
    print("hello world")

f()
>>>hello world

f.__call__ = lambda: print("foo") #replace the call operator

f()
>>>hello world

f.__call__()
>>>foo
```

something special is happening with `<class 'function'>`
could someone shine a light on this problem?

Comment: You have not changed the `__call__` method of a class.  You have changed the `__call__` method of a class instance.  That's the difference.  You would need to change the `__call__` method of the function class, which of course you don't really want to do.

Comment: @TimRoberts But don't instances first look at their own attributes before using attributes inherited from the class?

Comment: Usually, but `__call__` is different.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you write that as an answer, and cite the documentation that explains how it works?

Comment: "Usually, but call is different"
that is quite odd

Comment: Pretty much all of the double-underscored magic methods are looked up on the class, rather than the instance - `__call__` is nothing special here.

Comment: @jasonharper and how can we force the opposite behavior?

Comment: You can't; that's simply how the language works.  I guess it's mainly a matter of efficiency - in the normal, basic usage of classes, a method will NEVER be found on the instance, only on the class, so even checking for that possibility would be a universal slow-down.

Comment: _TypeError: cannot set '__call__' attribute of immutable type 'function'_ by trying to assign a custom `__call__`, and _TypeError: type 'function' is not an acceptable base type_ if you try to inherit from _function_:)

Comment: @DB3D Assumed that it were possible and your code work fine...then what kind of syntax do you expect? `f()()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not changed the `__call__` method of a class. You have changed the `__call__` method of a class instance. That's the difference. You would need to change the `__call__` method of the function class, which of course you don't really want to do.

The documentation on this is terse:

```
    Class Instances
        Instances of arbitrary classes can be made callable by defining
        a __call__() method in their class.
```

It specifically says "in their class", and not "in the instance".  This is just a design decision on Python's part.  You can imagine how confusing it would be if different instances of a class behaved differently in that case.

Comment: Your last point could be true for any method in any class, but Python allows methods to be attached to instances.

Comment: Yes. My actual guess is that this was done for optimization sake, to avoid an extra lookup for a common case.  That's just a guess.